# want to delete between certain 'word' and word' from a txt file in python

Tags: python, txt

I am trying to delete anything that starts with 'PROCESSING' and ends with '---' in this large txt file that i have. this is the current code I have atm:

```
with open('/Users/sebastian/Desktop/terms codes script clean/firmscodes.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
cleaned_lines = []
for line in lines:
  print(line[0], line[0:3])
  if all([line[0].isalpha(), line[1:3].isnumeric()]):
    cleaned_lines.append(line)
  else:
    print('skipping', line)
with open('test.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(cleaned_lines)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA6M7.png)

ive tried linestartwith and lineendwith to delete it

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: Where did you try to solve this using linestartwith and lineendwith?

Comment: Perhaps you should simply discard every line that doesn't begin with a firm ID, if you can guarantee a simple regex for that e.g. `[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{2}[0-9]`.

Comment: What's _anything_ in _anything that starts with 'PROCESSING' and ends with '---'_? There are no lines that end with _'---'_ in your example. Do you mean all text between those sequences, even if it span many lines?

Comment: Please add a text that we can copy-paste with an example of what should be deleted, and an example of how the final text would look like since you seem to want to delete more or less than a full line. See [mre].

Answer (score 0):

```
PATH= "../test_uca.txt"
NEW_PATH = "../new_file.txt"
SEARCH = ["PROCESSING","---"]
TMP = []
    
with open(PATH, 'r+') as f:
     text = f.read()
     for line in text.splitlines():
         if not line.startswith(SEARCH[0]) and not line.endswith(SEARCH[1]):
             TMP.append(line)
    
with open(NEW_PATH,"w") as f:
     f.write('\n'.join(TMP))
```